# Redirecting from HTTPS to HTTP

Tags: php, codeigniter, ssl, https, cloudflare

The webapp is built using CodeIgniter and the I'm using Cloudflare's Flexible SSL.

The pages load over HTTPS, but whenever there is a redirect, the page loads over HTTP. From then on, all pages are served over HTTP.

Here's an example:

```
public function logout()
{
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    redirect('/');

}
```

After the logout function, all pages are loaded over HTTP.

How can I ensure that pages load over HTTPS after redirects?

Here are the contents of my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
 <IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule> 

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.myurl.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Remove second `RewriteEngine On` line and put suggested cond/rule into `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>` block. Check also in `APPPATH.'config/config.php'` value of base url and put https there too.

Comment: For clarity, the value of the base url should be `https://www.myurl.com`, correct?

Comment: redirect with javascript insted of php `<script>window.location = "http://www.yoururl.com";</script>`

Comment: `https://www.myurl.com/` <- with slash at the end. Yes. Do you getting some errors now?

Comment: @Tpojka The issue was fixed by leaving my .htaccess file unchanged, but changing the base url in my config to https. Thank you for the suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy way might be to set base_url like so

```
$config['base_url'] = "https://yoursite.com/";
```

That will cause all CI functions that access `$config['base_url']` - which includes `redirect()` - to use https.

Not often talked about is the ability of `base_url()` to force a protocol by using a second argurment. e.g.

```
echo base_url("blog/post/123", 'https');
```

You can use .htaccess to force a redirect to the https protocol.
Put this above your existing commands.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```